# Hadoop mapreduce streaming from HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm building a Hadoop (0.20.1) mapreduce job that uses HBase (0.20.1) as both the data source and data sink. I would like to write the job in Python which has required me to use hadoop-0.20.1-streaming.jar to stream data to and from my Python scripts. This works fine if the data source/sink are HDFS files.

Does Hadoop support streaming from/to HBase for mapreduce?

Comment: Did you took a look to Hbase + Kafka + Spark Streaming integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what I want but it's not part of the Hadoop distribution. Any other suggestions or comments still welcome.

http://github.com/wanpark/hadoop-hbase-streaming

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953731/calculate-tf-idf-of-documents-using-hbase-as-the-datasource