# MapReduce on Hbase using Thrift in .NET?

Tags: .net, hadoop, hbase, thrift

Can i use Hadoop Streaming to Run MapReduce jobs on HBase using thrift in .NET? Or is there any other way to run MapReduce jobs on HBase from .NET?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I have successfully achieved this. So, the answer is yes it can be done.

**Edit**

I don't know why down votes, the question has the answer but following is how I achieved it:

Thrift is more light weight than REST API and in some scenarios gives more performance than java api, I've used Hadoop Streaming API and give it my own Mapper implementation which uses Thrift to communicate with hbase e.g.

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*-streaming.jar -input input/sample.txt -output output -mapper input/StdInOut.exe -reducer NONE
```

Comment: Could you please share with us your solution to the problem?

Comment: Seconded. Knowing it can be done is good to know, knowing *how* to do it would be better still.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the REST API ([stargate](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate)). However, neither the thrift or stargate servers are good ways to run a MapReduce jobs. Both require a separate daemon process that would be a single point of contention and wouldn't provide data locality. The java [mapreduce api](http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.89.20100924/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/package-summary.html) identifies data local regions for input splits. So the key is to use the java api with .Net. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706754/hadoop-mapreduce-streaming-from-hbase) provides a third party enhancement to streaming api for hbase, which would allow you use a .Net app via stdin/stdout.

Comment: But Thrift is more light weight than REST API and in some scenarios gives more performance than java api, I've used Hadoop Streaming API and give it my own Mapper implementation which uses Thrift to communicate with hbase, I've successfully able to execute my mapredue job in pseudo-distributed mode, but now i am going to test it in fully distributed mode, and i guess there should not be any problem as hbase uses HDFS as its data store.